# Difference between cblas_dcopy and dcopy in MKL?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, matrix, intel-mkl

What is the difference between cblas_dcopy vs dcopy? I am mostly using the dcopy because it is presented in the [official manual from Intel](http://www.cita.utoronto.ca/MISC/computing_guide/docs/Intel_Math_Kernel_Library_v5.1/doc/mklman51.pdf) to copy my matrices.

```
double* a = (double*)mkl_malloc(4 * 4 * sizeof(double), 64);
double* b = (double*)mkl_malloc(4 * 4 * sizeof(double), 64);
... calculations/operations ...
int one = 1;
int sxtn = 16;

dcopy(&sxtn, a, &one, b, &one);
```

Is this wrong? I have come across another way recently in the [online guide](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-10169923-CC6B-406A-AC40-8264490A4C2E.htm) form of:

```
cblas_dcopy(16, a, 1, b, 1);
```

What's the difference and which one should I use if I am using C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dcopy() is a function prototype for Fortran, while cblas_dcopy() is for C as indicated in [MLK ref manual](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-10169923-CC6B-406A-AC40-8264490A4C2E.htm#GUID-10169923-CC6B-406A-AC40-8264490A4C2E).

Due to the similarity of Fortran and C, you can call Fortran functions in C code by providing each parameter's pointer, just like what you did.

Of couse using C interface is better for C++.